# Getting Cannot process input of abstract type 'microsoft.graph.attachment'

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, postman, unirest

Am trying to create an attachment to my existing event and getting Cannot process input of abstract type 'microsoft.graph.attachment'".
How to fix this 422 Getting Cannot process input of abstract type 'microsoft.graph.attachment'

Am not able to find what is the problem in the below body

below is the postman body

[image]